# WebRTC PhoneGap plugin iOS native

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, webrtc

Does anyone have experience with WebRTC on iOS? I've found a nice PhoneGap plugin on GitHub https://github.com/alongubkin/phonertc and a nice native iOS example https://github.com/gandg/webrtc-ios which works with this turn server: https://apprtc.appspot.com.

I want to develop a PhoneGap iOS plugin by migrating functionality from the github's iOS sample to the PhoneGap implementation which is still at early stages and use https://apprtc.appspot.com as a signaling server. Does anyone done that before in order to provide me some guidance.

Any help is very much appreciate.

Comment: first of all, https://apprtc.appspot.com is not a turn server...

Comment: I was trying to say to extend the PhoneGap project with video support and test it with https://apprtc.appspot.com (obtain the turn server and the signalling like in the webrtc demo web).